# how to use md5() and crypt() together in php and msyql

Tags: php, md5, crypt

I want to use `md5()` and `crypt()` together in php login authentication.

I tried to use `md5(crypt(string),salt);` but i can't login in mysql.

Does anyone know how to use them together? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that `crypt` only uses the first two characters from `salt` and the first eight characters from `string`, and `md5` isn't considered safe for password hashing because it's too fast (http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html). Check if your system supports a newer hash function, such as Whirlpool or something from the SHA-2 family. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Cryptographic_hash_algorithms

Comment: Thanks outis, Yes, Md5 is not safe enough, so i try to use it with crypt. And the security level is higher than md5, and i can't decrypt it using md5 decryptor(http://www.md5decrypter.com/). And i can't find a way to decrypt the password in the format of md5(crypt($string, $salt)). I have read the article you have advised. It's cool and safe. And i also want to know how to use it. I use wamp server in windows. Do you have any advice? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the salt in the wrong function for a start:

```
md5(crypt(string,salt));
```

Also, assuming string and salt are variables you will need to prefix them with $:

```
md5(crypt($string,$salt));
```